# How to get default apache camel context id or create new one

Tags: java, spring, apache, error-handling, javabeans

I have a problem with application which is based on apache camel. I have few modules. In each of them I have camel routes definied in xml file, like this:

```
<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
       <route id="..." errorHandlerRef="myErrorHandler">
           ...
       </route>
       other routes...
</routes>
```

And application is working good. But when my application is shutting down I got an warning:

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'myErrorHandler': Singleton bean creation not allowed while the singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
```

Probably I got this warn because spring bean ('myErrorHandler' in this example) is shutting down before camel context is stopped. I red about some similar problems on apache camel forum, and people suggest to set depends on parameter on my beans which are used in camel ('myErrorHandler' bean), like here:

http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/quot-Singleton-bean-creation-not-allowed-while-the-singletons-of-this-factory-are-in-destruction-quon-td5713684.html

http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Spring-destroys-camelTemplate-before-CamelContext-td5464452.html

But in my case I don't have a camelContext element in my xml (as I shown, I have only 'routes' element), so it's hard to set depends-on to camel context id in my beans.

Any ideas how to solve this problem? Maybe I can set global camelContext id somewhere else and use it in my bean definition? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: your xml is part of some other common xml ? Routes are always defined inside camel context. Your application will definitely be having atleast one camel context.

Answer (score 0):

It only possible to define routes outside <camelContext/> which you do in a new <routeContext/> tag starting from Camel 2.3.
Quoted from : http://camel.apache.org/configuring-camel.html

Still you need camelContext to configure your routes. So my guess is your route xml's are getting imported in some common xml which will be having cameContext.
Just search for it and use it.

Answer (score 0):

I have few modules which are import to main module. I'm using spring boot maven plugin to start my application.
Each module has configuration class which import my camel file (which I show earlier) using own @CamelConfiguration annotation which works like this:

```
@CamelConfiguration("path to file which contains route definition")
public class MyConfiguration {
}
```

@CamelConfiguration is annotation created by other person, but it purposes is to load routes from specific localization.
Main application starts using SpringBoot like this:

```
SpringApplication.run
```

And class which start camel has annotation @SpringBootApplication. So, still I don't have a 'camelContext' element anywhere in my xml files.

I made something different. In 'myErrorHandler' bean class I autowired CamelContext (I have an access to object of this class). I hope if I do this spring doesn't destroy my beans while camel context exists (should works as depends-on) but it doesn't work. Still the same error...
So, finally, I'm not sure that depends-on will resolve my problem. Maybe I should try different solution?

EDIT: I'm using apache camel with spring boot like this:
http://camel.apache.org/spring-boot.html